# Input not being registered / registered too slowly in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a snake game in python (I'm quite bad at python, just starting with pygame so my code isn't the most effective) and the game is not responding to any keyboard inputs, I don't remember what I changed (shouldn't have been anything important enough to cut off keyboard inputs) but before I did this change, the code would run through the for statement 3 times before registering the keyboard input
Another problem I an having with the code which I haven't looked into much (so it's probably an easy fix which I'll find if I scan through my code) is that the snake spawns on the screen in the wrong pattern, it should be 3 blocks in a row, but is instead 2 blocks, 1 block space and 1 block

I realise that I have not implemented the fact that the snake tail should follow the head so please do not make a note of that in the comments, thanks

Here is my code (Just the snake class, I don't want to clutter up the screen with too much over-complicated, terrible code)

Under the code is a small explanation of some of the variables as they may not be too obvious

Thank you to anyone who helps out

```
class Snake:
    def __init__():
        Snake.Movement = "R"
        Snake.Front = 5
        Snake.Back = 3
        Apple.newPos()
        Snake.Move()
    def Move():
        while True:
            for event in p.event.get():
                if event.type == p.KEYDOWN:
                    #print("aaaaaaAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                    #if len(Snake.Movement) == 0:
                    if event.key == p.K_UP or event.key == p.K_w:
                        if Snake.Movement != "D":
                            print("DIRECTION UP")
                            Snake.Movement = "U"
                    elif event.key == p.K_DOWN or event.key == p.K_s:
                        if Snake.Movement != "U":
                            print("DIRECTION DOWN")
                            Snake.Movement = "D"
                    elif event.key == p.K_LEFT or event.key == p.K_a:
                        if Snake.Movement != "R":
                            print("DIRECTION LEFT")
                            Snake.Movement = "L"
                    elif event.key == p.K_RIGHT or event.key == p.K_d:
                        if Snake.Movement != "L":
                            print("DIRECTION RIGHT")
                            Snake.Movement = "R"
                t.sleep(1)
                for x in range(1,17):
                    for y in range(1,17):
                        if Setup.Screen[y][x] == 2:
                            p.draw.rect(Bg,(255,0,0),p.Rect(x*25,y*25,25,25),0,0)
                        elif Setup.Screen[y][x] != 0 and Setup.Screen[y][x] != 2:
                            if Setup.Screen[y][x] == Snake.Back:
                                p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,0,0),p.Rect(x*25,y*25,25,25),0,0)
                            elif Setup.Screen[y][x] == Snake.Front:
                                Snake.Front += 1
                                print(Snake.Movement)
                                if Snake.Movement == "U":
                                    if Setup.Screen[y+1][x] == 1:
                                        exit()
                                    else:
                                        p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,255,100),p.Rect(x*25,(y-1)*25,25,25),0,0)
                                        headX = x
                                        headY = y-1
                                elif Snake.Movement == "D":
                                    if Setup.Screen[y-1][x] == 1:
                                        exit()
                                    else:
                                        p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,255,100),p.Rect(x*25,(y+1)*25,25,25),0,0)
                                        headX = x
                                        headY = y+1
                                elif Snake.Movement == "L":
                                    if Setup.Screen[y][x-1] == 1:
                                        exit()
                                    else:
                                        p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,255,100),p.Rect((x-1)*25,y*25,25,25),0,0)
                                        headX = x-1
                                        headY = y
                                else:
                                    if Setup.Screen[y][x+1] == 1:
                                        exit()
                                    else:
                                        p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,255,100),p.Rect((x+1)*25,y*25,25,25),0,0)
                                        headY = y
                                        headX = x+1
                            else:
                                p.draw.rect(Bg,(0,255,100),p.Rect(x*25,y*25,25,25),0,0)
                            Snake.Back += 1
                            p.display.flip()
                try:
                    Setup.Screen[headY][headX] = Snake.Front
                except:
                    pass
```

- Setup.Screen[][] is a 2 dimensional array with numbers in the lists to associate with the different objects on screen (1 is a wall, 2 is an apple, 3+ is the snake).
- Snake.Front is an integer showing which number in Setup.Screen[][] the front of the snake is, as it changes each iteration.
- Snake.Back is the same as Snake.Front but for the back of the snake and isn't fully implemented yet.
- All of the print lines are from me trying to locate errors, they aren't needed

Comment: What actually is the *question*?

Comment: `t.sleep(1)` makes the game sleep for 1 second.